# Swapping values in an array using Pattern Matching in Scala

Tags: arrays, scala, pattern-matching

I am trying to solve the following problem from [Scala for the impatient](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321774094). The question is as follows:

> Using pattern matching, write a function swap that swaps the first two elements of an array provided its length is at least two.

My solution is:

```
def swap(sArr:Array[Int]) = sArr.splitAt(2) match { 
                               case (Array(x,y),Array(z)) => Array(y,x,z)
                               case (Array(x,y),Array()) => Array(y,x)
                               case _ => sArr
                            }
```

My problem is with the first case statement. I think it would pattern-match something like `(Array(1,2),Array(3))` whereas I intend it to pattern-match `(Array(1,2),Array(3,4,5.....))`

Can somebody point out how that would be possible.

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem with your code is that `Array(z)` means "match a one-element array".  What you want is for `z` to be the whole array, no matter how many elements:

```
def swap(sArr: Array[Int]) = 
  sArr.splitAt(2) match { 
    case (Array(x, y), z) => Array(y, x) ++ z
    case _ => sArr
}
```

However, I would write it with the sequence-matching syntax `_*` so that you don't have to manually split the array:

```
def f(a: Array[Int]) = 
  a match {
    case Array(x, y, z @ _*) => Array(y, x) ++ z
    case _ => a
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I guess the @ _* denotes the zero or more here for c?